# Emacs -- run-with-timer -- enter default choice if timer buzzes

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for an example, please, of setting a `run-with-timer` for the following choice scenario -- e.g., `(defvar git-window-options-timer 2-seconds)` -- if no selection has been made within 2 seconds, then automatically select option `?n`.  [The functionality would be similar to Grub or rEFIt.]

```lisp
(let* (
    (git-window-options (read-char-exclusive))
    (target-window (get-buffer-window git-status-buffer)))
  (cond
    ((eq git-window-options ?d)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer git-status-buffer)
        (delete-window target-window)))
    ((eq git-window-options ?k)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer git-status-buffer)
        (delete-window target-window)
        (kill-buffer (get-buffer git-status-buffer))))
    ((eq git-window-options ?n)
      (message "Done!"))
    (t (message "You have exited the sub-function.")) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SECONDS` option of `read-char-exclusive` as in

```
...
(git-window-options (or (read-char-exclusive nil nil git-window-options-timer) ?n))
...
```

should do the trick. Please, confer with the documentation of `read-char-exclusive`.

Comment: Thank you very much -- greatly appreciated!  :)  `(defvar git-window-options-timer 2)`  *If the optional argument SECONDS is non-nil, it should be a number specifying the maximum number of seconds to wait for input.  If no input arrives in that time, return nil.  SECONDS may be a floating-point value.*